# How to identify MongoDB text index using PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

With PyMongo, MongoDB 3.6, I can list the indexes for a `collection` with `list_indexes` as the documentation says [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.list_indexes). Is it possible to know if a given index is of type text by looking at its attributes?

A text index retrieved is something like this:

```
SON([('v', 2), ('key', SON([('_fts', 'text'), ('_ftsx', 1)])), ('name', 
'full_text_index'), ('default_language','english'),
('language_override', 'language'), ('ns', 'tiquetaque.employees'), 
('weights', SON([('contract_data.department', 1), ('full_name', 1), ('nis', 
1)])), ('textIndexVersion', 3)])
```

Is it enough to check if `textIndexVersion` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to know the index from the attributes. The key for an index has this information. You can convert from SON data about an index to a dictionary and check this.

```
def find_index_by_type(collection, type_):
    indexes = (index.to_dict() for index in collection.list_indexes())
    matches = [index for index in indexes if type_ in index['key'].values()]

    return matches

# text indexes in collection named collection.
print(find_index_by_type(db.collection, 'text'))

# hashed indexes in collection named collection.
print(find_index_by_type(db.collection, 'hashed'))
```